# Javascript Countdown with PHP

Tags: javascript

I want to have a countdown associated with a particular button on my PHP page and i am using following code based on javascript
But,it resets the target value on page reload,so how to have the same without the target value  getting reset.Can i do something with session ??

```
    <html>
    <body>
<p>Time remaining: <span id="countdownTimer"><span>00:00.<small>00</small></span></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (document.getElementById('countdownTimer')) {
    pad = function(n, len) { // leading 0's
        var s = n.toString();
        return (new Array( (len - s.length + 1) ).join('0')) + s;
    };

    function countDown() {
        var now = new Date();
        if ( (now.getDay() >= 0) && (now.getDay() <= 6) ) { // Monday to Friday only
            var target = 23; // 15:00hrs is the cut-off point
            if (now.getHours() < target) { // don't do anything if we're past the cut-off point
                var hrs = (target - 1) - now.getHours();
                if (hrs < 0) hrs = 0;
                var mins = 59 - now.getMinutes();
                if (mins < 0) mins = 0;
                var secs = 59 - now.getSeconds();
                if (secs < 0) secs = 0;
                var str = pad(hrs, 2) + ':' + pad(mins, 2) + '.<small>' + pad(secs, 2) + '</small>';
                document.getElementById('countdownTimer').innerHTML = str;
            }
        }
    }
    var timerRunning = setInterval('countDown()', 1000);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want properly persistent storage or will transient be ok? Session would work, as would a simple cookie on the client.

Comment: You are not properly closing your `countdownTimer` span. And never pass a string to `setInterval`, but use a function reference (in your case: `setInterval(countDown, 1000)`).

Comment: i want persistent storage but how to work out with sessions??

Comment: what do u mean by target value getting reset? is the 0's that come initialy after page load?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of evaluating your variable 'now' as such:

```
var now = new Date();
```

Evaluate it like this (assuming our browser supports LocalStorage):

```
if (!localStorage.myDate)
    localStorage.myDate = (new Date()).toString();
var now = new Date(localStorage.myDate);
```

This way, we only ever evaluate the current date on first load.  After that, we refer to a serialized string version of that date and pass that as an argument when we create our 'now' variable.

If we want to support older browser (*cough* IE), we can use userData or simply do something very similar with cookies.

Answer (score 0):

So essentially, you want to capture 'now' once, and not have that change, correct?

```
function getNow(){ //call this rather than use var now = new Date();
  if (window.localStorage){
      if (!localStorage.now){
        localStorage.now = new Date();
      }
      return localStorage.now;
  }else{
    return new Date();
  }
}
```

Pardon if I've got a bit of syntax out (I'm not sure if you'd have to convert a date to store it in localStorage), but that's the gist of it. For IE7 and below support you'd need to use cookies, but the concept remains the same.

Also, I think you have a mistake in:

```
 if ( (now.getDay() >= 0) && (now.getDay() <= 6) )
```

That will always be true, try:

```
if ( (now.getDay() > 0) && (now.getDay() < 6) )
```